# Are Android adapters asynchronous?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-adapter

I looked at [this example](https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android) from Google, it's an adapter on an `AutoCompleteTextView` that makes a network call to an API to retrieve auto-complete suggestions.

It doesn't use `AsynkTask` or threads, but doesn't give `StrictMode` warnings and doesn't lock the UI when there's no internet connection and I'm wondering why.

Is the `ArrayAdapter` itself asynchronous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Filtering perfomed asynchronously.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html)

> Filtering operations performed by calling [`filter(CharSequence)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#filter%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) or [`filter(CharSequence, android.widget.Filter.FilterListener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#filter%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.Filter.FilterListener%29) are performed asynchronously. When these methods are called, a filtering request is posted in a request queue and processed later. Any call to one of these methods will cancel any previous non-executed filtering request.

Answer (score 1):

Base `Adapter` classes ( including `ArrayAdapter`) so far, do not contain any *data fetching* mechanisms. You have to set data via `add()`.

The auto-complete method described uses filtering. `ArrayAdapter` implements `Filterable`. This particular implementation runs filtering methods in a separate thread. You can see the [source here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/widget/Filter.java#Filter.filter%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Candroid.widget.Filter.FilterListener%29).